# Replace serial in zone files with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to replace the serials in my zone files, and I thought the easiest would be to use sed to change this. I have the following line to test.

```
@ IN SOA    ns1.domain.com. webdev.domain.com. (
        2006080401  ; serial
        8H      ; refresh
        2H      ; retry
        1W      ; expire
        4h)     ; minimum ttl

        NS  ns1.domain.com.
        NS  ns2.domain.com.
        MX 10   mail1.domain.com.
        MX 20   mail2.domain.com.

domain.com.      A   255.255.255.255
mail1           A   255.255.255.255
mail2           A   10.10.10.10

www         CNAME   domain.com.
ftp         CNAME   www
webmail     CNAME   www
```

The regular expression I've created using http://rubular.com/ is the following. On rebular it the regex I got matches only one line.

`\s*[0-9]\s;\s*serial`

So in sed I would use this as follows.

`sed -i 's/\s*[0-9]\s;\s*serial/20091218 ; serial/g' *.zone`

My problem is that this doesn't change anything in the file. I've tried several things already. Thx for your help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need an asterisk after the second "\s"

```
sed -i 's/\s*[0-9]\s*;\s*serial/20091218 ; serial/' *.zone
```

And it might not hurt to put a couple more things in there as well:

```
sed -i 's/^\s*[0-9]\s*;\s*serial\s$/20091218 ; serial/' *.zone
```

I took out the "g" since you probably won't have multiple occurrences on one line.

Comment: found my problem, actually it was just an old version of sed and egrep I used. I thought regex hadn't changed that much since 2003 :)

Thx for your answers though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about preserving the leading spaces you can simply do:

```
awk '/serial/{$1=20091218}1'
```

#### Result1

```
@ IN SOA    ns1.domain.com.     webdev.domain.com. (
20091218 ; serial
        8H              ; refresh
```

On the other hand if getting the serial to line up is important to you, you can do:

```
awk '/serial/{printf "%8s%-16s; %s\n"," ",20091218,$3;next}1'
```

#### Result2

```
@ IN SOA    ns1.domain.com.     webdev.domain.com. (
        20091218        ; serial
        8H              ; refresh
```

This will line up perfectly as long as you keep the serial# less than 16 digits.

Comment: Great code, thank you. Here is a version that recursively moves through directory and replaces serial in every file:
`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 awk '/serial/{printf "%6s%-18s; %s\n"," ",2014121101,$3;next}1'`

Answer (score 1):

Your sed pattern looks for exactly one digit. This works for me:

```
sed -i 's/\s*[0-9]\+\s;\s*serial/20091218 ; serial/g' *.zone && cat *.zone
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perl method that worked well for me:

```bsh
cat /var/named/zonefile.db | perl -e "while(<>){ s/\d+(\s*;\s*[sS]erial)/20091218\1/; print; }"
```

Preserve leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," '/serial$/{$0="20091218 ; serial"}1' OFS="," file
```